# how can I remove the list of language setting in the source level of android?

Tags: android

There are many languages list for countries in the setting menu -> language & keyborad -> Select language....

so I just want to remove some list it means the device will show 5 language list.
for example English, china, japan, korean, france.

but I could not find the profer source code out to remove lists.
this class LocalePicker. I thought the languages is being read from getAssets().getLocales(); by assetManager.

please let me know the solution how do i remove them. 
via my email sence4u@hanmail.net.

thank you.

Comment: Via email? That would be a bit besides the purpose of stackoverflow, now wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

current setting for language ~~~

language/country/timezone etc.

/data/property dir
persist.sys.timezone
persist.sys.language
persist.sys.country

vender/!company/!project/
init.rc

## for default langudage

setprop persist.sys.language ko 
setprop persist.sys.country KR 
setprop persist.sys.timezone Asia/Seoul

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is relevant to anyone else but depending on which languages support file your device's makefile includes, you will need to modify the file that contains a list of Locales supported. This file will be found at **/build/target/products/languages_xxx.mk**