# How to give more language option in android for localization

Tags: android

I am new to android. I am working on localization. My Language is not listed ( Because of no support). for now I added font and its showing there in application, but there is no option for switching between language. To do so how I can add "mr Marathi" in Android?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Refer [this](http://www.slideshare.net/martyhall/android-tutorial-localization-l10n-internationalization-i18n-and-resources). The two letter codes are from ISO 639-1 language codes.

According to that, its mr fro "mr Marathi". Check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) one. 
Just add a res/values-mr and check in a phone which supports Marathi.

Hope it works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already running application with same approach. I want to give language option in setting->Input and Languages-> Marathi.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511741/adding-removing-the-language-entries-in-the-settings-select-locale-from-a .. In case the app doesn't provide the required language, try rooting it and install cwm from market as mentioned in http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-tab-10-1/475549-adding-more-languages.html. not sure if it'll work